# How to change the Kaa administration UI port from 8080 to another port in Ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: kaa

How do I change the Kaa administration UI port from 8080 to another port in Ubuntu 16.4?

I changed the `admin_port` field of the `kaa-node.properties` file but it doesn't work.

Comment: I hope you restarted the service after that change (`sudo service kaa-node restart`). What's the error you get when you are trying to access the admin UI on browser? Have you enabled the new port in Ubuntu for external access?

Comment: yes, I restart the kaa-node service and open the outgoing port in ufw firewall.
This is the error I got in chrome browser. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I'm using kaa sandbox

Comment: I'm not sure about the sandbox. Does it allows to change its config?

Comment: It has a config file named kaa-node.properties in conf folder.